# How to manipulate circles in d3 bubble diagram?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Sorry for the silly question, I'm just a poor d3 newbie...

I have the following [demo bubble diagram](https://jsfiddle.net/oeaq1d9z/1/) on JSFiddle: what I am trying to achieve is to increase the radius of the circles whenever I click over them and, after that, to adjust the pack layout accordingly.

This is the code in JSFiddle for your convenience:

```css
text {
  font: 20px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
        
var root = {
    "name": "Root",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Leaf One",
            "children": null,
            "size": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Leaf Two",
            "children": null,
            "size": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Leaf Three",
            "children": null,
            "size": 1
        }
    ],
    "size": 1
};

    
var diameter = 400,
    format = d3.format(",d"),
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
    .sort(null)
    .size([diameter, diameter])
    .padding(1.5);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
    .attr("class", "bubble");

// not needed in JSfiddle, data is hard-coded:
// d3.json("data.json", function(error, root) {
//   if (error) throw error;

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
      .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
    
    node.on("click", function(e, i){
    var circle = svg.select("circle");
    circle.attr("value", function(d) { 
     d.value += 1;
     return d.value; 
    });
    circle.attr("r", function(d) { 
     d.r += 1.0;
     return d.r; 
    });
      });
// });

// Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
function classes(root) {
  var classes = [];

  function recurse(name, node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
    else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
  }

  recurse(null, root);
  return {children: classes};
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

</script>
```

I tried to do that via the `node.on("click", ...)` method but I got somehow stuck, as the modified circle is always the first one: what is the best way to select the circle I clicked?

Besides, how can I force the d3 pack layout to refresh after I modify the circle radius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you have to remember that in event handlers the `this` is bound to the current DOM element (in out case - the `<g>`). so you can select clicked `<g>` by `d3.select(this)`, and then select the circle within:

`var circle = d3.select(this).select("circle");`

(by just doing `svg.select("circle")` you select the first circle in the DOM, which always happens to be the same one)

in order to **refresh the layout** you have to update the underlying data,  recalculate layout, recompute data join, and update values:

```
// store the underlying data in a value
var classedRoot = classes(root);

// ...your node creating code here

node.on("click", function(d) {
   // update the data in classedRoot
   d.value += 1;

   // recalculate layout
   var data = bubble.nodes(classedRoot);

   // recompute data join
   node.data(data, function(d) { return d.className; }) // use key function
      // update values
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
      .select("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r });
});
```

note the use of [key function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) here to properly bind updated data with the circles already present. the value you use must be unique for all circles. i used *className* here, but if it's not unique, you'll have to use some kind of Id.

here's updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oeaq1d9z/9/)

Comment: Well, perfect! I really appreciate.